# Different buckets give different outputs at first time step during decoding

Tags: tensorflow

**Background**

I'm trying to build a chat bot and have a basic understanding of tensorflow Sequence2Sequence API by reading from here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/

I've also read related papers for Neural translation, attention mechanism during encoding/decoding etc.

RNN translate code is taken from here:
http@s://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py

Bucketing/Attention mechanism code is picked from here:
http@s://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/legacy_seq2seq/python/ops/seq2seq.py

During my training(attention mechanism, GRU cell), I gave my buckets as [(2,2),(4,4),(6,6),(,8,8),(10,10)].

**Issue**

During decoding, if I force a bucket_index on the same input I'm getting totally different outputs at the first time step. For example:

Input : How're you ?
Bucket index : 1

Output : NAME UNK NAME

Input : How're you ?
Bucket index : 2

Output : Hi NAME to the

**Observations**

I can fix the bad outputs at each time step using beam-search. However, why I'm getting different word as output at the first time step during decoding ? Shouldn't the smaller bucket output be a subset of larger bucket output ?

I've tried searching online and everywhere it's mentioned that parameters are shared across various buckets. Buckets are used for training efficiency and not for model tuning. I've also verified that my trainable parameters are common across all the buckets.

The biggest difference I can see between encoder inputs for various buckets is the extra padding at the very start. We are doing attention mechanism on encoded_states, and softmax weights are already learned for those encoded states during training. Therefore, Can those softmax weights for those extra padded inputs cause sufficient difference leading to different output during first time step of decoding ?

Did any one else also encounter the above issue? Any help for fixing the above error would be greatly appreciated.

I've also opened an issue here because I'm unsure whether it is a bug(file on github), or my mis-understanding(Stackoverflow):
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/7561

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have figured out an answer for this. I would like to comment on this in case someone else wants an idea on this.

I believe this is the expected behavior. If you check the source implementation of model_with_buckets function in TensorFlow, you see roughly the following lines of code:

```
for j, bucket in enumerate(buckets):
    with variable_scope.variable_scope(
        variable_scope.get_variable_scope(), reuse=True if j > 0 else None):
        bucket_outputs, _ = seq2seq(encoder_inputs[:bucket[0]],
                                    decoder_inputs[:bucket[1]])
        outputs.append(bucket_outputs)
```

If you use 5 buckets, then this above outputs list will contain 5 sub-lists. In each of sub-list, it contains the decoder_outputs for each bucket. This outputs will be returned, and will be used both for training and prediction. You can see that each decoder_output (singular form) in different buckets are normally different as they are trained to generate outputs that match different targets for different buckets (although the variables in different buckets are re-used).

One interesting test you can do is: add to your training set a pair with short question but long answer (make sure your model is big enough to remember almost every training samples). This means, this pair will use a larger bucket in the training, but a smaller bucket in the prediction. You also need a mechanism to type in your pad token in string format, say, *pad*. After your model is trained, perform such a prediction test. Type in the original answer, you will very likely get a totally different/meaningless answer. However, you then type in your question followed with a number of *pad* until the input sentence is long enough so that the desired bucket can be chosen. You will then very likely get the same exact answer in that new training pair.

Hope this explanation makes sense.

Comment: Another interesting test is to create training data with padding at the beginning sentences of the questions. For example: 1) How are you? Fine, thank you. 2) _pad_ How are you? Doing good, thank you. 3) _pad_ _pad_ How are you? Great. How about you? You can see that all these can be trained to remembered exactly. Now you know the difference between different buckets are not because they can different weights, but sequences of paddings.

Comment: Also, if you use GRUCell, you may be able to get very close answers from different buckets. Although some time small buckets may not cut the last part of your training answers (looks randomly cut some part). Also it may fill the length of the decoder without ouput the eos token.